# Unity player position loading error

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

First of all, I am not sure this is the right place to post this topic sorry about that.
I am using XAMPP and MYSQL to create my database everything works well but when I close the game and try to load the last position the player just teleports to the origin.

C# Code on unity:

Dataloader script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DataLoader : MonoBehaviour {
    public int playerxd;
    public int playeryd;
    public int playerzd;
    public string[] pos;
    IEnumerator Start(){

        WWW posData = new WWW("http://localhost/BegoneBD/DataPos.php");
        yield return posData;
        string posDataString = posData.text;
        print (posDataString);
        pos = posDataString.Split(';');
        print(GetDataValue(pos[0], "x:"));
        print(GetDataValue(pos[0], "y:"));
        print(GetDataValue(pos[0], "z:"));
    }

    string GetDataValue(string data, string index)
    {
        string value = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(index) + index.Length);
        if (value.Contains("|")) value = value.Remove(value.IndexOf("|"));
        playerxd = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
        return value;
    }
    string GetDataValue2(string data, string index)
    {
        string value = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(index) + index.Length);
        if (value.Contains("|")) value = value.Remove(value.IndexOf("|"));
        playeryd = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
        return value;
    }
    string GetDataValue3(string data, string index)
    {
        string value = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(index) + index.Length);
        if (value.Contains("|")) value = value.Remove(value.IndexOf("|"));
        playerzd = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
        return value;
    }

}
```

Save Script

```
public class Save : MonoBehaviour {
    public string[] pos;
    bool teste;
    float playerx;
    float playery;
    float playerz;
    int inputplayerx;
    int inputplayery;
    int inputplayerz;
    string CreateUserUrl = "http://localhost/BegoneBD/InsertPos.php";
    public void SavePosition()
    {
        playerx = transform.position.x;
        playery = transform.position.y;
        playerz = transform.position.z;
        inputplayerx = (int)playerx;
        inputplayery = (int)playery;
        inputplayerz = (int)playerz;
        CreatePos(inputplayerx, inputplayery, inputplayerz);
    }
    public void CreatePos(int playerx1, int playery1, int playerz1)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("playerxpost", playerx1);
        form.AddField("playerypost", playery1);
        form.AddField("playerzpost", playerz1);
        WWW www = new WWW(CreateUserUrl, form);
    }
    public void LoadPosition()
    {
        DataLoader f = new DataLoader();
        f.playerxd = (int)playerx;
        f.playeryd = (int)playery;
        f.playerzd = (int)playerz;
        transform.position = new Vector3(playerx, playery, playerz);
    }
    public void CursorSaveOn()
    {
            Cursor.visible = true;

    }
    public void CursorSaveOff()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;

    }
}
```

PHP Code for connection with the database:
Datapos.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username =  "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "begonebd";

//Make Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
//Check Connection
if(!$conn){
    die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, x, y, z FROM playerposition";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    //show data for each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "id:".$row['id'] . "|x:".$row['x']. "|y:".$row['y']. "|z:".$row['z'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Insertpos.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username =  "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "begonebd";
$x = "-240";
$y = "2";
$z = "-247";

$x = $_POST["playerxpost"];
$y = $_POST["playerypost"];
$z = $_POST["playerzpost"];
Make Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
Check Connection
if(!$conn){
    die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
else echo("Connection Success");

$sql = "SELECT id, x, y, z FROM playerposition";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);


$sql = "INSERT INTO playerposition (x, y, z)
        VALUES ('".$x."','".$y."','".$z."')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);

if(!result) echo "there was an error";
else echo "Everything ok.";

?>
```

Thanks in advance, this is really important for me since this is a school project and I cant do the presentation without the database working properly.-

Comment: And in your debugging where did it go wrong, why is GetDataValue exactly the same as GetDataValue2 except it saves one in x and the other in y..  where do you think its going wrong

Comment: I dont have much experience on programming but from where I've searched the problem seems to be on the connection with the database on php files.
GetDataValue uses the same exact code since I'm just selecting the text that appears on the browser from DataPos.php the only thing that changes is what I'm selecting in DataValue1 is X 2 is y and 3 is z.

Comment: what is the printed value of posDataString, why do you split it by ; not |

Comment: The print value is the value I get from the database. I cant exactly tell you why it is splited by : and not | since I cant understand it really well myself.. I was watching some youtube tutorial and he did the same.
https://youtu.be/3pcvJYJinn4?t=6m30s

Comment: You sound like me.. Im following a unity tutorial and Im now so far away from the tutorial its almost not worth watching it . in mine, he did say "Make your own choices" sadly what I thought initially was a small choice is turning into an epic pain.  My guy keeps saying "You dont need to understand that yet" and yet I clearly do..